# Why I am not getting exact data when I am using rest api with MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I am getting following data when I am using MongoDB Rest API.

```
Cursor id=0, ns=test.products, query={ }, numIterated=1,    addr=localhost/127.0.0.1:27017, readPreference=primary
```

I am expecting JSON data, but I am not getting that data.
For this i am maintaining following URL

```
localhost:8080/API/rest/applicationInitiatorService/addContact
```

Please find the below Code

```
   import javax.ws.rs.*;    
   @Path("/applicationInitiatorService/")
   public class ApplicationInitiatorService {
    @GET
    @Path("/addContact")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response add_Contact() {
        DBCursor cursor=null;
        cursor=ApplicationInitiatorFactory.getApplicationinitiator().add_record(getcCollection);
        String addrecord=cursor.toString(); 
        return Response.status(200).entity(addrecord).build();   
   }}
```

And find Respected method where I am calling a method.

```
public DBCursor add_record(DBCollection db_collection) {
    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("database", "Bosch_DB");
    document.put("table", "generating");
    BasicDBObject documentDetail = new BasicDBObject();
    documentDetail.put("total_phone_no", 100);
    documentDetail.put("vps_index", "vps_index1");
    documentDetail.put("active", "true");
    document.put("detail", documentDetail);
    db_collection.insert(document);
    DBCursor cursorDoc = db_collection.find();
    while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursorDoc.next());
         }
return cursorDoc;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This data is comming your REST api, please check the api code and see whats happening there. My guess is you are returning the incorrect variable.

Could you include the code from your API call ?

UPDATE:
I would suggest you change:

```
String addrecord=cursor.toString();
```

to:

```
String addrecord=cursor.next().toString();
```

Comment: I am returning a DB Cursor Object

Comment: Could you supply the code? You have the return the results of the find. I'm guessing it's something in that part of your code

Comment: status is 200. But I am getting Cursor id=0, ns=test.products, query={ }, numIterated=1,    addr=localhost/127.0.0.1:27017, readPreference=primary

Comment: I had updated my question and provide necessary information which is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably something to do with cursor or toString. Could you try converting the cursor data to a collection and return it?

```
public DBCursor add_record(DBCollection db_collection) {
    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("database", "Bosch_DB");
    document.put("table", "generating");
    BasicDBObject documentDetail = new BasicDBObject();
    documentDetail.put("total_phone_no", 100);
    documentDetail.put("vps_index", "vps_index1");
    documentDetail.put("active", "true");
    document.put("detail", documentDetail);
    db_collection.insert(document);
    return db_collection.find();
}
```

Something like

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;    
@Path("/applicationInitiatorService/")
public class ApplicationInitiatorService {
    @GET
    @Path("/addContact")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response add_Contact() {
        DBCursor cursor = ApplicationInitiatorFactory.getApplicationinitiator().add_record(getcCollection);
        return Response.status(200).entity(cursor.toArray()).build(); 

    }
}
```

or you can try the return statement as

`return Response.status(200).entity(new Gson().toJson(cursor.toArray())).build();`

For this you will need to use [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7) library.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't switch cursor access methods getting this Exception.

Comment: @Santosh updated my answer. Please see if it works. The can't switch cursor access error is probably because you were doing cursor.next before cursor.toArray()

Comment: I think it will return some compilation problem  return db_collection.find();.